# VBA Sub to create Excel Sheets for Days of Month Change 01-31 to 1st to 31st

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet, concatenation

I have found this VBA Sub to rename sheets for the days of the month but I want to change the out put of the names.  Currently it goes 01, 02, 03, 04 .... 30, 31.  I want it to go 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ...22nd, ...30th, 31st.  Here is code.  I was able to add post string with this function as well but still have the leading zeros in the less than 10 values.

```
Function Addth(pNumber As String) As String
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20160628
Select Case CLng(VBA.Right(pNumber, 1))
    Case 1
    Addth = pNumber & "st"
    Case 2
    Addth = pNumber & "nd"
    Case 3
    Addth = pNumber & "rd"
    Case Else
    Addth = pNumber & "th"
End Select
Select Case VBA.CLng(VBA.Right(pNumber, 2))
    Case 11, 12, 13
    Addth = pNumber & "th"
End Select
End Function


Sub DoDays()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim sDay As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iTarget As Integer
    Dim dBasis As Date

    iTarget = 13
    While (iTarget < 1) Or (iTarget > 12)
        iTarget = Val(InputBox("Numeric month?"))
        If iTarget = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sTemp = Str(iTarget) & "/1/" & Year(Now())
    dBasis = CDate(sTemp)

    For J = 1 To 31
        sDay = Addth(Format((dBasis + J - 1), "dd"))

        Addth (sDay)


        If Month(dBasis + J - 1) = iTarget Then

            If J <= Sheets.Count Then
                If Left(Sheets(J).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
                    Sheets(J).Name = sDay
                Else
                    Sheets.Add.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
                    If sDay <= 9 Then sDay = Format((dBasis + J - 1), "d")
                End If
            Else
                Sheets.Add.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
            End If
        End If
    Next J

    For J = 1 To (Sheets.Count - 1)
        For K = J + 1 To Sheets.Count
            If Right(Sheets(J).Name, 10) > _
              Right(Sheets(K).Name, 10) Then
                Sheets(K).Move Before:=Sheets(J)

            End If
        Next K
    Next J


    Sheets(1).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to use a `"d"` format for your days instead of a `"dd"` format, change `sDay = Addth(Format((dBasis + J - 1), "dd"))` to `sDay = Addth(Format((dBasis + J - 1), "d"))`.  `sDay` will then take values such as `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, `4th`, ...`22nd`, ...`30th`, `31st`.

Comment: right then i get the order 10th, 11th, 12th...19th, 1st, 20th, 21st....29th, 2nd, 30th, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th.  I want the order to be 1st to 31st in order.

Comment: Sorry - the question didn't mention the sorting of sheets you are doing after you create them, so I didn't notice it.  From the looks of your code, I think you can keep them in order if you remove the final `For j` loop that is sorting them into alphabetical order.  (As far as I can see, prior to that loop they are in numerical order.)  And, of course, remove the `Addth (sDay)` line which will crash out.  And the `If sDay <= 9 Then sDay = Format((dBasis + J - 1), "d")` line is redundant.

Comment: Tested - removing the final loop will leave them in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks, can you post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display dates using a `"d"` format (i.e. single digit output for single digit days, and double digit output for double digit days) instead of in a `"dd"` format (i.e. double digit output for both single and double digit days), you should change the line saying

```
sDay = Addth(Format((dBasis + J - 1), "dd"))
```

to be

```
sDay = Addth(Format((dBasis + J - 1), "d"))
```

---

Your refactored `DoDays` code could be:

```
Sub DoDays()
    Dim J As Long
    Dim sDay As String
    Dim iTarget As Integer
    Dim dBasis As Date

    iTarget = 13
    While (iTarget < 1) Or (iTarget > 12)
        iTarget = Val(InputBox("Numeric month?"))
        If iTarget = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'I changed this next line because I live in a dd/mm/yyyy locale, and your
    'existing line was specific to a mm/dd/yyyy locale.  Using DateSerial gets
    'rid of those sort of issues.
    dBasis = DateSerial(Year(Now()), iTarget, 1)

    For J = 1 To 31
        sDay = Addth(Format(dBasis + J - 1, "d"))

        'This line will crash once "sDay" is "1st" because "st" isn't numeric
        'i.e. CLng(VBA.Right(pNumber, 1)) will get upset with it
        '(I assume it was only in your code while you were testing various things.)
        'Addth (sDay)

        If Month(dBasis + J - 1) <> iTarget Then
            Exit For ' No use processing 30 and 31 if no 29th in this month
        End If

        If J <= Worksheets.Count Then
            If Left(Worksheets(J).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
                Worksheets(J).Name = sDay
            Else
                Worksheets.Add.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
            End If
        Else
            Worksheets.Add.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
        End If
    Next J

    'This loop sorts sheets into alphabetic order, and is not needed because
    ' sheets are desired to be in existing order
    'For J = 1 To (Sheets.Count - 1)
    '    For K = J + 1 To Sheets.Count
    '        If Right(Sheets(J).Name, 10) > _
    '          Right(Sheets(K).Name, 10) Then
    '            Sheets(K).Move Before:=Sheets(J)
    '        End If
    '    Next K
    'Next J

    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: does anyone have code for this in javascript for google docs?

Answer (score 0):

- Determine how many days in the month
- Add that many worksheets to the workbook
- Rename the Worksheets

Note: I created an array to ordinal numbers from 1 to 31.  In this way, the day number will return the correct ordinal name.

```
Sub DoDays2()
    Dim iMonth As Integer, DaysInMonth As Integer, i1stSheet As Integer, x As Integer

    Do
        iMonth = Val(InputBox("Numeric month?"))
        If iMonth = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf iMonth >= 1 And iMonth <= 12 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(Now), iMonth + 1, 1) - 1)

    'For some reason the Worksheets are actually inserted before the last Worksheet.
    Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=DaysInMonth
    i1stSheet = Worksheets.Count - DaysInMonth

    For x = 0 To DaysInMonth - 1
        Worksheets(i1stSheet + x).Name = Split("1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd 24th 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st", " ")(x)
    Next

    'Move the worksheet Back
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Move Before:=Worksheets("1st")

End Sub
```